# What does git pull . do?

Tags: git, git-pull

When I run it on my git repo this is what I get.

```
git pull .
From .
 * branch            HEAD       -> FETCH_HEAD
Current branch rel_20121207 is up to date.
```

But when I run just `git pull` it actually updates from the remote.

I would like to know what exactly happened when I ran `git pull .`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ha, this one's fun. `git pull` takes a remote name, *or* a file spec. You're giving it a file spec ('`.`' means the current directory), so it's treating your current repo like a remote, and throwing your current HEAD into FETCH_HEAD. You're pulling your repo into itself; essentially it's doing nothing.

Comment: funny! I haven't noticed the infamous '.' in the question! +1 :D